# Close an Opened JInternalFrame that is been opened within another JInternalFrame while changing the tab of a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jinternalframe

I've created and application in which there are two tabs titled **Tabbedpane 1** and **Tabbedpane 2**. In one tab body **Tabbedpane 1** contains a `JInternalFrame` in which there is a search button. On clicking the button another `JInternalFrame` opens within the main `JInternalFrame`.

Can anyone please tell me how to close the said opened `JInternalFrame` ie the search `JInternalFrame` while clicking on to the second tab titled **Tabbedpane 2**

I've tried `.setClosed(true)` and `.setVisible(true)` on property change still it does'nt works for me.

Comment: Please post your code here it should be short and runnable/compliable ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) which will get notified when `JTabbedPane` state changes (i.e tabs switched):

```
final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
       //tab has been changed
    }
});
```

The problem is we will need a way to monitor the previous tab i.e the tab we were on before it was changed this can be done via:

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    int prev_index = 0;
    int curr_index = 0;

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        prev_index = curr_index;
        curr_index = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();

        System.out.println("Tab (Current): " + curr_index);
        System.out.println("Tab (Previous): " + prev_index);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

To close `JInternalFrame` I'd suggest calling `dispose()` on its instance

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is your fixed code, basically added a getter for `Search` class, thus `JIFrame1` has a `getSearch()` method which allows us to gaim access to the Search classes current instance created in `JIFrame1`, in `changedState(..)` I call `jiFrame1.getSearch().dispose()` which will make sure we dispose of the instance that has already been created:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Sample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JIFrame1 jiframe1 = new JIFrame1();

    public Sample() {
        initComponents();

        Container jiframe1cont = tab1;
        for (MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) jiframe1.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()) {
            ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) jiframe1.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }
        jiframe1.setLocation(10, 10);
        jiframe1cont.add(jiframe1);
        jiframe1.setVisible(true);

        JIFrame2 jiframe2 = new JIFrame2();
        Container jiframe2cont = tab2;
        for (MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) jiframe2.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()) {
            ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) jiframe2.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }
        jiframe2.setLocation(10, 10);
        jiframe2cont.add(jiframe2);
        jiframe2.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        tab1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        tab2 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(javax.swing.JTabbedPane.LEFT);
        tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                tabbedPaneStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        tab1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tabbedpane 1", tab1);

        tab2.setBackground(javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.background"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tabbedpane 2", tab2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 731, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 503, Short.MAX_VALUE));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void tabbedPaneStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
        try {
            jiframe1.getSearch().dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Sample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane tab1;
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane tab2;
    private final javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    // End of variables declaration
}

class Search extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public Search() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jTextField1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
                }));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton1.setText("CLOSE");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 385, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(205, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(158, 158, 158)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(172, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        this.dispose();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}

class JIFrame1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public JIFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        pane = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        pane.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));

        jButton1.setText("SEARCH");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.setBounds(170, 60, 90, 23);
        pane.add(jButton1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(pane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 567, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(pane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 322, Short.MAX_VALUE));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
    private Search search;

    public Search getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        search = new Search();
        Container searchcont = pane;
        for (MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) search.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()) {
            ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) search.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }
        search.setLocation(10, 10);
        searchcont.add(search);
        search.setVisible(true);
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane pane;
    // End of variables declaration
}

class JIFrame2 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public JIFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setText("JIFrame2..............");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(137, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(145, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

The reason for NPE is here:

```
private void tabbedPaneStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
        try {
            jiframe1.getSearch().dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

change to this:

```
private void tabbedPaneStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    try {
        Search s=jiframe1.getSearch();
        if(s!=null)
        s.dispose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but how to close the opened search JInternalFrame . i tried  try {
            new Search().setClosed(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: @NidhinKrishnan Also not by using the `new` keyword you create a new instance of Search each time you should call `dispose()` on  the previously created instance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20960/discussion-between-nidhinkrishnan-and-david-kroukamp)

Comment: @NidhinKrishnan dont have the time right now sorry, but i fixed the code see update 3